# Read BLOB to string in PHP (Symfony2)

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, blob

I have a MYSQL DB where I store encrypted credentials for an IMAP account.
The field for the password is a BLOB as recommended.

```
        $encrypter = new TripleDES(CRYPT_DES_MODE_ECB);
        $encrypter->setKey($this->container->getParameter('secure_token'));
        $encrytped_pw = $encrypter->encrypt("MYPASSWORD");

        $mailbox->setUrl('{outlook.office365.com:993/imap/ssl}');
        $mailbox->setUsername('user@domain.tld');
        $mailbox->setPassword(base64_decode($encrytped_pw));
        $em->persist($mailbox);
        $em->flush();
```

Unfortunately I am not able to decrypt this field with this:

```
    $mailboxPw = $this->getUser()->getMailbox()->getPassword();

    $decrypter = new TripleDES(CRYPT_DES_MODE_ECB);
    $decrypter->setKey($this->container->getParameter('secure_token'));
    $decrytped_pw = $decrypter->decrypt(base64_encode($mailboxPw));
```

as it gives me

```
Warning: base64_encode() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given
```

I cannot find a way to convert a blob resource to string, is there anotther way to achieve what I want?

Any hint appreciated

Comment: What kind of resource is it? Add result of this code to your question.  echo get_resource_type($mailboxPw);

Comment: It gives me `stream` but when I do `stream_get_contents` it just gives me false (cannot decrypt), I think the way I store it may be wrong already?

Comment: removed the base64_encode/decode, now it works!!!

Comment: you should post your solution as answer and accept it. this way the solution can be found more easily.

Answer (score 0):

The resource might be read with **stream_get_contents**:

```
$mailboxPwResource = $this->getUser()->getMailbox()->getPassword();
$mailboxPw = stream_get_contents($mailboxPwResource);

$decrypter = new TripleDES(CRYPT_DES_MODE_ECB);
$decrypter->setKey($this->container->getParameter('secure_token'));
$decrytped_pw = $decrypter->decrypt(base64_encode($mailboxPw));
```